# Maven + Surefire + @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) annotation

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a Maven project where I want to run Junit 4 and 5 test cases. Some of the JUnit5 test cases also uses @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) annotation to run with Junit4.  However, I have not been able to run both Junit 4 and 5 test cases in the same project so far.

See the code below. To compile JUnitPlatformClassDemoTest, I would need to add "junit-platform-runner" dependency in pom.xml, but the moment I add it, Maven ignores JUnit 5 test cases.

I have tried various combinations but nothing seems to work. Note that if I remove JUnitPlatformClassDemoTest class, then Maven is able to run the remaining Junit 4 and 5 test cases successfully. Problem seems to be only with @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) annotation.

How do I configure Maven such that it can run Junit 5 and 4 test cases and the tests which have @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) annotation ?

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>junit45</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit45</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>   
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opentest4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentest4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- After adding this dependency JUnit 5 test cases are ignored -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </plugin>               
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

SampleTest class

```
package example;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class SampleTest {

    List<String> list;

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void join() {
        list.add("foo");
        list.add("bar");
        Assertions.assertEquals("fooXbar", String.join("X", list));
    }

    @Test
    public void unjoin() {
        String joinedString = "fooXbar";
        String[] values = joinedString.split("X");
        Assertions.assertArrayEquals(new String[] { "foo", "bar" }, values);
    }
}
```

JUnit4Test class

```
package example;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JUnit4Test {

    @Test
    public void dummyTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

JUnitPlatformClassDemoTest class

```
package example;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class JUnitPlatformClassDemoTest {

    @Test
    void successTest1() {
        System.out.println("successTest1");
    }

    @Test
    void successTest2() {
        System.out.println("successTest2");
    }
}
```

Comment: To run JUnit 4 and JUnit Jupiter tests you have to add the [vintage engine to run them both](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-running) apart from that in your example you are mixing JUnit 4 and JUnit Jupiter imports

Comment: @khmarbaise, vintage is already included in pom.xml shown above. Also, not sure what you mean by "mixing JUnit 4 and JUnit Jupiter imports" - JUnitPlatformClassDemoTest needs to have junit 4 imports due to RunWith and JUnitPlatform. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Yes but your `JUnitPlatformClassDemoTest` contains `@Test` from JUnit Jupiter and not from JUnit 4...

Comment: @khmarbaise, on JUnitPlatformClassDemoTest it does not make any difference. I replaced it with Junit 4 Test, and it still works fine. Problem is with Junit 5 tests (SampleTest class). Maven is simply ignoring this test class.

Comment: Can you make a working example on github or alike...

Comment: @khmarbaise, here it is - https://github.com/niajthat/junit45

Comment: Created PR..furthermore the given example `@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)` is usually not needed because this is intended for running on IDE's/tools which do not support JUnit Jupiter Engine which I don't know any of...also there has been missed a package name for one of the classes which cause issues because a class in default package will be ignored...correct.

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks for spending time on this, however, as I mentioned earlier in the original post I had no problems running Junit 4/5 tests together when junit-platform-runner was not added in pom. Also, for now let's assume I have a valid use-case which needs @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) in my test. To keep this, I would need to add junit-platform-runner dependency in pom and that's when JUnit 5 tests stop working.

Comment: Which use case? as I mentioned in the pr you have to add a correct package into a java file which you hadn't...remove the usage of @RunWith in relationship with JUnit 4 or related to JUnit Jupiter it does not makes sense...

Comment: We have the same issue and our use case would be to run tagged tests and for this we need the @RunWith annotation. However, having the junit platform allows us to run the suite of junit 5 tests, but not their classes individually or any other test that comes from the junit.jupiter api.